# Return simple text String with ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I return a simple text String like below, basically I want to display a simple text for my error in the browser.

I handle my error in here and here I want to do it:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception e) {

}
```

The problem is I have to return a ModelAndView. How can I return a simple text to the browser, do not want to use any JSP etc.

Just return the same way like below or similar:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
```

For example this does not work:

```
return new ModelAndView((View) ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `@ExceptionHandler` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html):

> Handler methods which are annotated with this annotation are allowed
>   to have very flexible signatures. They may have parameters of the
>   following types, in arbitrary order: [...] OutputStream / Writer for
>   generating the response's content. This will be the raw
>   OutputStream/Writer as exposed by the Servlet API. [...]

So you could define an exception handling method which looks something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public void handleAllException(Exception e, Writer responseWriter) {
  responseWriter.write(e.getMessage());
}
```

You can obviously do something more complex to format the error message, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score -2):

You could do:

```
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception e) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("your_jsp_name");
    modelAndView.addObject("name", "Peter");
    ...
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: And where do I put my JSP in SpringBoot structure? Any other configuration needed?

Comment: OP asked how to return a plain text response without using jsp at all.

Comment: Dont know how your project structure is, but you could try just putting the name of the file you want the text to be displayed to.

Comment: If that doesnt work, try putting the jsp in:

src/main/resources/public/


Example without jsp:

https://g00glen00b.be/spring-webapp/